# How can I get the regions around local maxima in a 3-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have a *large* 3D numpy array (1024 x 1024 x 1024), and I need to find the regions around local maxima so that all neighbouring points with a value greater than, e.g., 50% of the local maximum, are recursively clustered in the same region. An iterative algorithm would be:

- Loop over local maxima, from highest value to lowest value.
- If the local maximum is already assigned to a region, `continue` looping over the next local maximum.
- If the local maximum is not assigned to any region, assign it to a new region. Let the value of that local maximum be M.
- Add to the region all neighbours of the local maximum with a value > 0.5*M.
- Recursively add to the region all neighbours, neighbours of neighbours... with a value > 0.5*M.
- Repeat until all local maxima are assigned to some region.

For such a huge array this algorithm is prohibitive, so I was looking for some vectorized solution with the Python libraries.

More specifically, for a 2D array such as

```
0.0  1.6  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  5.0
1.6  3.0  1.0  0.0  4.6
0.0  0.0  0.0  9.0  4.6
```

there would be two such regions:

```
                    5.0
                    4.6
               9.0  4.6
```

and

```
     1.6               
     2.0               
1.6  3.0
```

Intuitively, I am looking for the "mountains" around local maxima, where a "mountain" is defined by a contour level that is not absolute but relative to the local maxima.

I have tried using `scipy.ndimage`, which is quite useful to first find the local maxima. But I do not know how to get the regions around them. I also had a look at standard clustering algorithms and image processing techniques such as blob detection or local thresholding, but none seemed to reproduce this problem.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: thanks to taw, a solution is the following

```
import math
import numpy as np

def soln(data, maxind):
    test = np.pad(data,(1,1),'constant',constant_values = [-math.inf,-math.inf])
    regionlist = {} # Dictionary with the results
    for region, ind in enumerate(maxind):  # Loop over all maxima
        M = test[ind[0]+1, ind[1]+1, ind[2]+1] # Value of the maximum

        if M == -np.inf:
            continue

        regionlist[region] = set()
        regionlist[region].add(ind)

        test[ind[0]+1, ind[1]+1, ind[2]+1] = -math.inf # All points that are added to the results are set to -infinity
        neighbors = set()
        neighbors.add((ind[0]+1, ind[1]+1, ind[2]+1))
        while len(neighbors)>0: #create region iteratively
            newneighbors = set() # This will contain the new elements in the region
            for i in neighbors: 
                values = test[i[0]-1:i[0]+2, i[1]-1:i[1]+2, i[2]-1:i[2]+2] # Values of neighbours
                valuesmask = values > .5*M # Neighbours that fall in region
                list1 = range(i[0]-2, i[0]+1)
                list2 = range(i[1]-2, i[1]+1)
                list3 = range(i[2]-2, i[2]+1)
                indlist = list(itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)) # 3-D list with coordinates of neighbours
                for count,j in enumerate(valuesmask): 
                    if j:
                       newneighbors.add(indlist[count])

            #update iteration
            newneighbors = newneighbors.difference(neighbors) # Remove all elements that were already iterated over and added to regionlist
            regionlist[region].update(newneighbors) # Add the new elements in the region to regionlist
            neighbors = set((x[0]-1, x[1]-1, x[2]-1) for x in newneighbors) # In the next iteration, iterate only over new elements in the region
            for i in newneighbors:
                test[i[0]+1, i[1]+1, i[2]+1] = -math.inf #set values to -inf after added to region

    return regionlist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how "local maxima" is being defined, or what functions in scipy.ndimage you are using to get them. Here is a function that will give the set of indices belonging to each region (returns indices, not the values). Cost looks like O(number of points which will be assigned to regions). The constant depends on the dimension of the array. I don't think it's possible to do better than this (in terms of the complexity).

Also this solution works on 2d arrays.

```
import math
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[0, 1.6, 0, 0, 0,], [0, 2, 1,0,5],[1.6,3,1,0,4.6],[0,0,0,9,4.6]])

maxind = [(3,3),(2,1)] #indices of maxima
def soln(data, maxind):
    test = np.pad(data,(1,1),'constant',constant_values = [-math.inf,-math.inf])
    regionlist = {}
    for region,ind in enumerate(maxind):  #all maxima
        regionlist[region] = set()
        regionlist[region].add(ind)
        M = test[ind[0]+1,ind[1]+1]
        test[ind[0]+1,ind[1]+1] = -math.inf
        neighbors = set()
        neighbors.add((ind[0]+1,ind[1]+1))
        while len(neighbors)>0: #create region iteratively
            newneighbors = set()
            for i in neighbors: 
                values = test[i[0]-1:i[0]+2,i[1]-1:i[1]+2]
                valuesmask = values.flatten() > .5*M
                list1 = np.repeat(list(range(i[0]-2,i[0]+1)),3)
                list2 = np.tile(list(range(i[1]-2,i[1]+1)), 3)
                indlist = list(zip(list1,list2))
                for count,j in enumerate(valuesmask): 
                    if j:
                        newneighbors.add(indlist[count])

            #update iteration
            newneighbors = newneighbors.difference(neighbors)
            regionlist[region].update(newneighbors)
            neighbors = newneighbors
            for i in newneighbors:
                test[i[0]+1,i[1]+1] = -math.inf #set values to -inf after added to region

    return regionlist

regionlist = soln(test, maxind)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is relatively fast for my needs. I am getting the local maxima (points greater than all their nearest neighbors) using `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252357/how-can-i-get-the-regions-around-local-maxima-in-a-3-d-array/59257997#59257997). I have updated the question with the proper 3-D extension and a minor bug fix: I believe that, in your example, `neighbors` contains the coordinates of the points in the `data` array, whereas according to the loop it should contain the coordinates in the `test` array.